# How to click on "Verify you are human" checkbox challenge by cloudflare using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe, cloudflare, webdriverwait

I need to automatically download using Python a .csv file that is in this web page:

```
https://pace.coe.int/en/aplist/committees/9/commission-des-questions-politiques-et-de-la-democratie
```

Now, I have written this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
 
chromedriver_path = r"./driver/chromedriver"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
url = "https://pace.coe.int/en/aplist/committees/9/commission-des-questions-politiques-et-de-la-democratie"
topics_xpath = '//*[@id="challenge-stage"]/div/label/span[2]'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5)  #Wait a little for page to load.
escolhe = browser.find_element("xpath", topics_xpath)
time.sleep(5)
escolhe.click()
time.sleep(5)
```

The web page opens up and I am then prompted to click on "Verify you are human":

[image]

I have "inspected" the button and copied the xpath (see code above).
But I get this error:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="challenge-stage"]/div/label/span[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.198)
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Did you considere that whoever implemented that humanity check would do their very best to make clicking it automatically impossible or as hard as possible? And that they might be opposed to you doing that, even if you got a solution to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [checkbox](/questions/tagged/checkbox) associated with the text ***Verify you are human*** element is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://pace.coe.int/en/aplist/committees/9/commission-des-questions-politiques-et-de-la-democratie")
    time.sleep(5)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='Widget containing a Cloudflare security challenge']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label.ctp-checkbox-label"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://pace.coe.int/en/aplist/committees/9/commission-des-questions-politiques-et-de-la-democratie")
    time.sleep(5)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='Widget containing a Cloudflare security challenge']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@class='ctp-checkbox-label']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: Curious: Does this actually defeat the non-automation check?  If so, it would seem to be a rather weak check.

Comment: This allows to click the check box but the cloud fare doesn't re-direct to the required website post that... maybe it is able to detect the bot behaviour

Comment: Yes. I've tried and it clicks on the box, but the cloudflare stays on

Answer (score 5):

Here's a complete [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) script for bypassing Cloudflare on that site.

`pip install seleniumbase`, then run with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

def verify_success(sb):
    sb.assert_element('img[alt="Logo Assembly"]', timeout=8)
    sb.sleep(4)

with SB(uc_cdp=True, guest_mode=True) as sb:
    sb.open("https://pace.coe.int/en/aplist/committees/9/commission-des-questions-politiques-et-de-la-democratie")
    try:
        verify_success(sb)
    except Exception:
        if sb.is_element_visible('input[value*="Verify"]'):
            sb.click('input[value*="Verify"]')
        elif sb.is_element_visible('iframe[title*="challenge"]'):
            sb.switch_to_frame('iframe[title*="challenge"]')
            sb.click("span.mark")
        else:
            raise Exception("Detected!")
        try:
            verify_success(sb)
        except Exception:
            raise Exception("Detected!")
```

It will only click the checkbox if necessary. Use `sb.driver` to access the raw `driver`. The script tries to avoid detection altogether.

Comment: Thanks Michael, awesome Framework! 

Comment: The solution can bypass Cloudflare but after some seconds, it raises an Exception. Has Cloudflare updated its security and can detect this framework now?

Comment: Cloudflare occasionally updates their Turnstile page. Eg, different timings, different selectors for the checkbox, etc. It might require upgrading to the latest SeleniumBase version. This script stays up-to-date: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/raw_uc_mode.py (although not necessarily this post).